# Need a precise tutorial for serializing and deserializing a hierarchy of classes in c#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Please provide me with a precise tutorial/web-link for serializing and deserializing a hierarchy of classes in c#.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class:

```
var instance = new SomeClass();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeClass));
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, instance);
}
```

and to deserialize:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeClass));
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("output.xml"))
{
    var instance = (SomeClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

The serialization/deserialization process could be [controlled by using attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx).

Another popular class commonly used for XML serialization is the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) which is used by WCF but could be used in any application.

Comment: (as a side note to the OP; DataContractSerializer might not give you quite the *idiomatic* xml that you might expect from XmlSerializer - nor does it give you much control to influence the layout (but it is indeed worth mentioning; it does a few things that XmlSerializer *can't* - but it isn't a 1:1 replacement)

Answer (score 0):

At the most basic, xml serialization can be as simple as spinning up an `XmlSerializer` and using it. However, you can use [many many attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to influence the serializer, or use `XmlAttributeOverrides` if you can't annotate. In particular, since you mention hierarchy, you'll want:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(SomeDerivedType))]
public class Foo {}

public class SomeDerivedType : Foo {}
```

Other notes on `XmlSerializer`:

- the type must be public
- only public properties and fields are considered
- there must be a public parameterless constructor (or a default constructor)
- it is a *tree* serializer, so object references are not preserved (you can use `[XmlIgnore]` to avoid upwards navigation on "parent" properties)
- you can also implement `IXmlSerializable` if you want custom serialization, but I don't recommend it
- serializer callbacks are not supported

Answer (score 0):

[Deep Serialization: Binary and SOAP Serialization with a Generic Twist](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/Coreweb03.aspx)

> Serialization allows you to convert a
>   graph of objects into a linear
>   sequence of bytes, XML, or SOAP. Once
>   an object is flattened, you can store
>   it or send it over the wire.
>   Serialized data can then be
>   deserialized. Deserialization
>   essentially reconstitutes the graph of
>   objects you initially serialized.
>   Serialization sounds complicated, but
>   in practice, it's pretty easy because
>   the .NET framework takes care of most
>   of the complexity for you.

Comment: The question tags call for xml serialization... which is not really covered by that article *at all*. It touches on `SoapFormatter`, but that class is essentially obsolete. In fact, IMO ***none*** of the methods detailed in that article should be used... ever.